# Сложение чисел с разными знаками в Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Только начал освоение Java, и для теста решил сложить два числа.

```
double b = 14.6;
double a = -15.8;
double sum=0;

    sum = a + b;

    System.out.println("Сумма чисел равна " + sum);
```

Но в ответ выходит:

```
> Сумма чисел равна -1.200000000000001
```

Очень интересно, почему так много знаков после запятой и откуда единица в конце?
Если изменить знак переменной "а" на положительный, результат получается с одним знаком после запятой. Работаю в Eclipse.
Как решить эту проблему, если это вообще проблема?